# Angular routes always redirecting to the home page

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am trying to make my routes work, and I have attempted various approaches. I even deleted the project and created a new one, but the same error persists: I cannot navigate to another page; it always redirects to the initial one.

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ShopComponent } from './shop/shop.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  { path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Answer (score 1):

When AppComponent is used to bootstrap the app in main.ts (as is the default), it should not be used in the routes.

`app.component.html` needs to contain `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in order for routing to work.

For the empty path route, you need to create a separate component, like `HomeComponent` for example.

Comment: this has not worked.

Comment: Do you bootstrap the app with AppComponent? Then it will always be displayed, regardless of routing. And if you have no `router-outlet` in that template, the other components will not show up, even if routing is ok.

Comment: I believe I am: bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
How should my main be?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. When I try to go to http://localhost:4200/shop or http://localhost:4200/home, it still goes to the initial screen of app.component.

Comment: Take a look at this [basic setup](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-routing-77634118?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot and solved my problem.